# Error: -bash: check_nrpe: command not found

Tags: nagios, nrpe

I am using Nagios XI. I issued following command from the Nagios Server:

`nagiossrv root [libexec] > check_nrpe -H 128.19.5.131 -t 30 -c check_users -w 5 -c 10`

It is giving me following error:

`-bash: check_nrpe: command not found`

I have also added the IP address of the Nagios server (nagiossrv) to the `/usr/local/nagios/etc/nrpe.cfg` file at the host's (128.19.5.131) side.

What is the issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a little research, I got above error resolved. Just had to enter the command as follows:

`nagiossrv root [libexec] > /usr/local/nagios/libexec/check_nrpe -H 128.19.5.131 -t 30 -c check_users -a '-w 5 -c 10'`

And the output would look like:

`USERS OK - 1 users currently logged in |users=1;5;10;0`